# Add time element to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a massive list of JavaScript arrays that look like this:

```
var filesArray = new Array(
   new Array('This is a description 2', 'imagename'),
   new Array('This is a description 3', 'image_2'),
   new Array('This is a description test', 'test'),
);
```

Each array contains information about an image, which are then get loaded into an HTML page. Every time a photo gets added to the gallery the admin adds a line to this array. I'm there's a better way to do this, but I don't know PHP.

I need to add a time element to these array items. For example, I need to be able to show photos by week. However,they all have to come from this main array, which has no date information at all.  Is this possible? Is there a better route?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use an object.** JavaScript objects can be instantiated like so:

```
var img = {
  file: 'someplace.jpg',
  time: '3:00',
};
```

Just populate an array of image objects, and you'll be good to go!

```
var images = [];
images.push({
  file: 'myfirstimages.jpg',
  time: '2:45'
});
images.push({
  file: 'mysecondimage.jpg',
  time: '3:15'
});
images.push({
  file: 'mythirdimage.jpg',
  time: '3:45'
});
```

You get the idea. You can also declare the array directly.
If you don't want to hard-code the time, I recommend using JavaScript's **[Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)**.

Comment: I'll have do some reading up on objects, how does this relate to the code I have in the arrays?

Comment: @jsheffers Instead of creating arrays to store information about images, use an object which represents an image.

Comment: Could you add an example with multiple objects?

Comment: You are hard coding the time, how would I auto-populate that?

Comment: Can I use the date object outside of the image objects, I don't want to have copy that for each object?

Comment: Just because you didn't like the fact that I unchecked your answer you down vote me? You missed one very important part of the question.  Yes I see that you can use JavaScript's date object, but I have no experience with that hence the reason I asked this question in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can add date as 3rd element of the array:

```
var filesArray = new Array(
   new Array('This is a description 2', 'imagename', new Date('10-10-2013')),
   new Array('This is a description 3', 'image_2', new Date('10-10-2013')),
   new Array('This is a description test', 'test', new Date('10-10-2013')),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are trying to save the date when an image was uploaded to the server. Thus, add an extra field to the already existing 2 (image and description). If I were you, I would create an array of objects:

```
var files = [
    {image: 'image1', description: 'description1', timestamp: function(){ return Date.now(); } },
    {image: 'image2', description: 'description2', timestamp: function(){ return Date.now(); } }
];
```

Then, if you want to access, let's say, image no.2, you would access it like this:

```
var image2 = files[1];

//access image2 description
var description = image2.description;
console.log(description) // this will return 'description2'
```